# Can't access SD card in SD card slot using Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sd-card

I have an unused SD card plugged into my SD card slot. When I try and go into it I get "Please insert a disk into Removable Disk (E:)". If I right click and click Format I get "There is no disk in drive E:". In Disk Management there is no option to create a partition on the drive. I have tried deleting the E: drive under Portable Devices in Device Manager and restarting.

Comment: Does the SD card work in other devices?  What was the last device you used the SD card in?

Comment: It is a micro SD card in a adapter. I tried putting the micro SD card in my phone but it did not recognise it.

Comment: @Jon30b The microSD is likely  dead.

Comment: I bought a new SD card and it's ok.